# jsf mailto replacing '+' with whitespaces

Tags: jsf, whitespace, mailto

I have a stupid problem with mailto and didn't find any solution.

My Code:

```
<h:outputLink value="mailto:#{bean.mailingList}">
  <f:param name="subject" value="Contact" />
  <f:param name="body" value="Dear Sir or Madam,..." />
  <b:button value="CLick me" look="primary"/>
</h:outputLink>
```

Everything works fine except of the body. Every blank space is replaced with "+". I can create a new line with "\n" so I'm wondering if there's something for this, too. Maybe returning an text/html string from the bean? Hope you can help me with that.

(I tried %20, encoding to utf-8 and replacing in the bean)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by replacing every whitespaces with "\r". :-)

Comment: Didn't work for me. I am trying to replace space in my subject field